# Creating polygons from sparse data in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I have a dataframe with coordinates for which I want to create polygons, the most normal is a polygon like the one I put in the first image:

[image]

But I'm looking for something different, more like this:
[image]

As you can see, if the points are enough far, another polygon is created, is this possible in R? Thanks!

Here are the data
[csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v360fIyYMM2W0PGIMf89I7hG5GlbkwUY/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would find the concept of concave/alpha hulls relevant. There's an R package `alphahull` that may cover your need.

```
install.packages("alphahull")
library(alphahull)
fff <- readr::read_csv("data.csv")
dddd <- ahull(fff[,2:3],alpha = 0.01)
plot(dddd)
```

And in case you need to convert this output into a spatial data format, please see the following:
https://babichmorrowc.github.io/post/2019-03-18-alpha-hull/